# Excel - Matching Colum Data between sheets

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have been given an excel workbook, with two sheets on them with quite a bit of data - this needs merging into one.  To keep matters simple:

Sheet 1

```
|Servers|
ABCD1
ABCD2
ABCD3
```

Sheet 2

```
|Servers|        |Policy|
ABCD1            PolicyA
ABCD3            PolicyB
```

What I'm after is to say; move the policies from Sheet 2 into Sheet 1, matching the policies to the Servers, however leave a blank where a server does not have a policy.

I've read about VLOOKUP but can't seem to get it working.

Any help would be great

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in Sheet1, Servers is in column A, place to following formula in column B:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),"No policy")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to make the values blank is an if function to check if the policy is there.

For **Excel 2007 and above**:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"")="", "", VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE))
```

For others:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)),"", IF(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)="", "", VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)))
```